# Computer won't wake up after suspend

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, ati, suspend

Okay so I have had this problem with several versions of linux two primarily being xubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 lts, But I have also experienced the issue with Cent OS 7. I have several issues with the current distro Ubuntu 14.04 and before I make it my primary OS I want to repair the issues. First is the waking issue, after I have closed my laptop and left it alone for several hours (sometimes not so long but sometimes I can go hours and not experience the issue) I open the laptop back up and it won't wake up from suspend. I literally have to turn the computer off and restart it. Which brings me to the next intermittent issue, after restarting the computer (sometimes not all the time) the mouse and keyboard doesn't work and it has to be restarted again to have them operational. neither of the problems are persistent but both are rather annoying. I am running a dual boot on a Toshiba Satellite L775 with Windows 7.

System specs as pulled from the terminal:

BIOS:

vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.30
          date: 05/11/2011
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi

dual core CPU:

product: AMD A4-3300M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1200MHz
          capacity: 1200MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt arat cpb hw_pstate npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter cpufreq

IDK if there is anything else that is needed but if there is I will gladly provide it.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2112830 okay so I have found this post here regarding a similar issue. I have made the necessary edits and am going to attempt this for the suspend issue, if I find anything else regarding other the other issues I will post them here as well. I am only looking for documentation or things that I can implement my self rather following directions or otherwise, I really want to learn how to operate the systems without just being handed the information. So if there are any bug reports or documentation I will take those as well.

Comment: Okay so that was fast, no repair, I will continue to look through this issue and I hope that one of you guys will be able to assist soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your video card driver? Check if the vendor has offered anything to download for Linux/Ubuntu. This could solve it for some PCs, although it didn't work for me.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, I need a new laptop, the one I am using is about 7 years old so it could be video card related

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my situation which I believe is similar.  The PC monitor "goes to sleep" overnight and can't be restored to life, even though I can hear from disc activity that the PC is not in hibernation. I installed VNC Server on the PC, so when I get to it in the morning I can VNC in from another PC and "wake it up" by adjusting the screen resolution.

I ought to implement a more systemic fix but this normally isn't an issue since I don't usually leave the PC on overnight.